Using a Body Class to override deep nested CSS classes in DIVs
I am encountering an issue using Wordpress and ECWID. Ecwid does not currently support limit product categories depending on their assigned customer group.
I have assigned customer groups in the Wordpress User enviroment and add this to the body class.
<body class="customer">

Now far further down in the imported ECWID shop (first div is named id="ecwid-store"). A product category consists of heavily nested divs.
The full "path" to one of these nested divs is:
/html/body/main/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]
Where the last div is the targeted div mentioned furhter down.
<div class="grid-category grid-category--id-144804312 grid-category--no-image">
<div class="grid-category__wrap"><div class="grid-category__wrap-inner">
<div class="grid-category__card"><a class="grid-category__image" title="Liggende" href="#!/Liggende/c/144804312" tabindex="-1">
<div class="grid-category__bg"><div class="grid-category__bg-color colored-background-2"></div>
<div class="grid-category__bg-image"></div></div><div class="grid-category__image-wrap">
<div class="grid-category__image-spacer"><div class="grid-category__image-spacer-inner"></div></div>
<div class="grid-category__picture"></div><div class="grid__clearfix"></div></div>
<div class="grid-category__shadow"><div class="grid-category__shadow-inner">Liggende</div></div></a><div class="grid-category__hover-wrap"></div>
<a class="grid-category__title" href="#!/Liggende/c/144804312">
<div class="grid-category__title-inner">Liggende</div></a></div>
<div class="grid-category__spacer"><div class="grid-category__spacer-inner"></div></div>
<div class="grid__clearfix"></div></div></div></div> 

Supposedly you are going to be able to access these nested divs using this code setup
.ec-size .ec-store.grid-category grid-category--id-144804312 {display: none !Important;}

Which is fine if you're onnly going to hide the ntire category for every user out there. BUT here's the catch. I need to hide this category from a select few. Let's call them "NewCustomer".
Now this does not work:
.newcustomer .ec-size .ec-store.grid-category grid-category--id-144804312 {display: none !Important;}
Neither does this (suggested by ECWID btw):
&.newcustomer .ec-size .ec-store.grid-category grid-category--id-144804312 {display: none !Important;}

Does anyone have any clue at all as how to get this CSS to work?
Can I use something like this?
.newcustomer > .ec-size .ec-store.grid-category grid-category--id-144804312 {display: none !Important;}

I really need help with this one.
Thank you for all inputs.

Can you [edit] the question and provide a runnable snippet ?


Supposedly you are going to be able to access these nested divs using this code setup

No, you won't be, because no elements with the tag names grid-category or grid-category--id-144804312 exist anywhere. These are supposed to be class selectors, so they need a . in front. And these aren't two elements, one nested into the other - this is one element, having both those classes. So there must be no space between those two either.
You want
.newcustomer .ec-size .ec-store .grid-category.grid-category--id-144804312 { ... }


You are correct about the missing punctioation. But that is just a typo in my question. I have corrected it in my post. I use of course the .grid-category.grid-category-- without spaces. The problem is still unsolved tho. But thank you for your input

@XanderMan then please use your browser dev tools, and inspect the element. Check if the rule applies to it at all - and whether the value of the display property still gets overwritten by something more specific, perhaps.

yeah, no. nothing gets loaded after my custom css. I have escalated this to ECWID. It seems the CSS is loaded but not executed somehow.
